# Custom date formatter is not outputting what I expect

Tags: c#, .net

Consider this:

`DateTime.Now.ToString("d") // 5/26/2016`

I expect the above to output "26", because "d" is the "day" specifier for a custom format.

This code outputs what I expect, but with a trailing space:

`DateTime.Now.ToString("d ") // 26`

But the docs say nothing of this!

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: Brandon, when you put space in the parameter C# assumes that you're trying to do a customize format that's why only the day was displyed.

Comment: See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx

Comment: I think the question is what does it assume I want without the space? I *am* trying to do a customized format.

Comment: Well there you go. Thanks, Blogbeard!

Comment: Also, from your own link, "If the "d" format specifier is used without other custom format specifiers, it is interpreted as the "d" standard date and time format specifier. For more information about using a single format specifier, see Using Single Custom Format Specifiers later in this topic."

Comment: Why the down and close votes? Question shows code with reproducible results, and some effort to look up what's going on in docs. Even though it's not a bug and the docs do explain it, it's still an acceptable question for this site if OP didn't understand it.

Answer (score 3):

It's the difference between a [Standard Format String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx) and a [Custom Format String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx). The two types of format strings are documented separately, but they are used by the same methods (not just `DateTime.ToString()` but also `String.Format()` and numerous other places). In order to able to interpret the same input as either type of format string, one must first check if the input matches a standard format string, and use a custom format if and only if that match fails, as explained in this excerpt from the documentation for Custom Format Strings:

> Any string that is not a standard date and time format string is interpreted as a custom date and time format string.

and from the documentation for Standard Format Strings:

> Any date and time format string that contains more than one character, including white space, is interpreted as a custom date and time format string;

In this case, `"d"` matches the standard format for a short date, hence the `5/26/2016` result (and you must be on the other side of the Atlantic from me). But `"d "` is not a standard format string, and when evaluated as a custom format string shows only the current day of the month.

If you just want the day of the month, without a trailing space, you can do this:

```
DateTime.Now.Day.ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("d ").Trim()
```

or

```
DateTime.Now.Day.ToString()
```